# Create 10 folds from data, but put the vlaues with the same ID in the same fold

Tags: r, r-caret

I need to make 10 folds from my data. The dataframe has 309 rows. some rows have similar IDs. I need to put the values with the same ID in each fold. In other words, I do not like the values with the same ID to be separated when I make the 10 folds. The table is similar to this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 3 | 11 |

I Used the following codes.

```
outflds <- createFolds(df$Value, k = 10, list = TRUE)
test.data <- df[outflds[[1]],]
train.data <- df[-outflds[[1]],]
```

The problem with these codes is that it shuffles the data randomly and cannot keep the values with the same ID in one fold.
How can I keep the values with the same ID in the same fold?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `groupKFold` if you want to keep the same groups, in this case id's, together.

Example based on your table. using 3 folds (k needs to be equal to or smaller than the unique number of ID's).

```
set.seed(4242)
folds <- groupKFold(df1$ID, k = 3) 
folds

$Fold1
[1] 1 2 3 4

$Fold2
[1] 3 4 5 6

$Fold3
[1] 1 2 5 6
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Value = c(10L, 
12L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This is a great help. I appreciate your help Phiver.